# Check the audio levels of public YouTube live stream programmatically

Tags: java, audio, youtube

I am broadcasting around 20+ live streams on YouTube every day. Most of these streams go live for more than 5+ hours.

For the purpose of Live streaming, I am using **Zoom** and directly live-streaming a Zoom meeting. The Zoom meeting is held in a room with **multiple cameras covering multiple points** and **microphones capturing voices** of various participants at various points in the same room. In order to monitor the streams, I currently view each and every stream one by one and check the stream health and voice levels on **Youtube Studio**.

As it's challenging to individually monitor each stream and ensure that they all have good audio levels. Therefore, I am seeking a programmatic approach to check the audio levels of these streams and receive notifications when they drop below a certain threshold.

Although I've attempted to use the `YouTube iframe API` and `YouTube Data API`, neither has been successful in providing any data or input with regard to the audio levels.

Even though I would prefer an answer based on `java` I'm open to any solution or method using other languages such as  `PHP`, `Python`, or even simple `JavaScript` *(if possible)*.

I don't want the code in the process of live streaming is being done, but instead, I want it outside the process of live streaming. After the live stream has started and it's ongoing I want to check at periodic intervals as a third party viewing the various streams to make sure that all the streams have good audio levels.

Answer (score 1):

## Requirements

- [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)
- Some YouTube video down loader like [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)

## Download a sample of the video stream

- Left to the reader to figure out how to download the stream or part of it.
- Be sure to not modify the audo codecs but rather just copy on the download.

## Check loudness with ffmpeg

```bash
ffmpeg -i "${INPUT_VIDEO}" -filter:a ebur128 -map 0:a -f null -
```

```bash
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 0x7ff0cf70a600] Summary:

  Integrated loudness:
    I:         -23.2 LUFS
    Threshold: -35.7 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:        18.8 LU
    Threshold: -45.7 LUFS
    LRA low:   -38.5 LUFS
    LRA high:  -19.8 LUFS
```

Typical Linear TV `I` is about `-24`

A nice read on [LUFS](https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/what-are-lufs.html) meanings

## Example of an automated solution

I think a simple bash script on a timer could do the trick for what you a looking for.

Here is an idea of what could be done.

- requires [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)
- Note: if processing multiple files at once might use `mktemp` and `TRAP` to create random files, and auto remove them after the script runs.
- `audio.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

timeout_duration=10
audio_format=opus

stream_url=${1? must provide stream url}
output_file="/tmp/video.${audio_format}"
log_file="/tmp/audio.log"

function clean() {
  rm -rf "${output_file}"
  rm -rf "${log_file}"
}

function download_media() {
  # download timeout (10s) amount of audio file
  timeout ${timeout_duration} yt-dlp \
    --ignore-errors \
    --format bestaudio \
    --extract-audio \
    --audio-format ${audio_format} \
    --audio-quality 160K \
    --output "${output_file}" \
    "${stream_url}"
}

function read_audio_levels() {
  # read the audio files loudness settings
  ffmpeg \
    -i "${output_file}" \
    -filter:a ebur128 \
    -map 0:a -f null - 2> "${log_file}"
}

function parse_log() {
  # parse the output
  lufs=$(cat "${log_file}" | rg -A 1 'Integrated loudness:' | rg -o 'I:\s*(.*)\s*LUFS' -r '$1')
}

function print_level() {
  echo "===================================="
  echo "Stream Integrated loudness: ${lufs}"
  echo "===================================="
}

clean
download_media
read_audio_levels
parse_log
print_level
clean
```

## usage

- chmod +x audio.sh
- ./audio.sh "https://somevideostream.net"

Comment: To add, besides ffmpeg also VLC has the option to normalize audio volume of video (streams)

Answer (score 0):

use selenium and both java and python have selenium library you can use it to automate browser or Youtube

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on Producer side might be tedious and affects the performance of the system.

One approach that I can think of is setup a new client which can acts as a consumer, check the output volume of the client system. If the quality of sound goes below the threshold, then you can trigger an alert to your monitoring system.

But how you'll define "sound quality", is depending on your requirements, might be based on noise level or any other metrics.